# Deploy in production Outlook web-addin?

Tags: node.js, webpack, outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am totally new to NodeJS, Webpack and especially to Outlook Addin.

However, when it came to deployment on Production, I struggled a lot. I put all my code up on Production (Ubuntu instance). Then I tried to start my Outlook Addin, just like I was doing locally, it started on port 3000, but there was no response to any API call and it is not showing any images which are static resources.

I want to know what could be the reason behind this and how to solve this problem.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        polyfill: 'babel-polyfill',
        app: './src/index.js',
        'function-file': './function-file/function-file.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            chunks: ['polyfill', 'app']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './function-file/function-file.html',
            filename: 'function-file/function-file.html',
            chunks: ['function-file']
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Please make sure you are able to access any of the html pages of your add-in by the URL (or IP) of your ubuntu instance in a browser. You will have to check how your web server is configured. An outlook web add-in is nothing but a web page / website. Go through these docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio-code

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot of error you are getting? What API you are calling from addin which is failing currently?